# Not able to get stripe payment token in iOS Swift

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, cocoapods, xcode13.3.1

I am implementing stripe paymentSDK and after implementing my code I am getting error in my console, here my code:

**View Controller Class**

```
 func stripPayment(CVC:String){
    // Initiate the card
    let stripCard = STPCardParams()
    if cardMM == "" && cardYY == "" {
    // Send the card info to Strip to get the token
        stripCard.number=card_number
        stripCard.name=card_name
        stripCard.cvc=CVC
        stripCard.expYear=UInt(cardYY)!
        stripCard.expMonth=UInt(cardMM)!
    }
    print("card_number:",card_number)
    print("card_name:",card_name)
    print("CVC:",CVC)
    print("cardYY:",cardYY)
    print("cardMM:",cardMM)
    STPAPIClient.shared.createToken(withCard: stripCard) { (token: STPToken?, error: Error?) in
        print("Printing Strip response:\(String(describing: token?.allResponseFields))\n\n")
        print("Printing Strip Token:\(String(describing: token?.tokenId))")
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }
        if token != nil{
            print("Token:",token!.tokenId)
            self.placeOrderApi(tokenStripe: token!.tokenId, completion: {
                self.pushVC(id: "PaymentConfirmationVCID")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**App Delegate DidFinishLaunch**

```
STPAPIClient.shared.publishableKey = "pk_test_51KuLPhJ4jB1YaTRoUayoteEXbtl5QvbayNeDDhjv4Nto9UvdM4LcTsP2EXAbU0IuOoKsIsOAk565HzvjLRPVP9wY00Ro5T3PYq"
```

**Error I am getting in console**

Printing Strip Token:nil
Optional(Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds" UserInfo={com.stripe.lib:ErrorParameterKey=card[number], NSLocalizedDescription=There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=Missing required param: card[number]., com.stripe.lib:StripeErrorTypeKey=invalid_request_error, com.stripe.lib:StripeErrorCodeKey=parameter_missing})
There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds

Comment: I would suggest to login into stipe dashboard and check if there any logs related to the issue that you are getting.

Comment: I check dashboard logs and there it is showing same error [Missing required param: card[number]] I have tried by placing static parameter from my code but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say what the problem is without showing where `card_number` is defined and what type it is. Your code overall does work given appropriate values like

```
let card_number = "4242424242424242"
let card_name = "Jane Doe"
let CVC = "123"
let cardYY = "27"
let cardMM = "12"
```

But putting that aside, it's unusual to collect the raw card details and create Tokens like this and post them to a backend, it's a legacy integration. I'd suggest using Stripe's current integrations and plug-in payment components directly instead https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios

Comment: I tried by putting static parameters still showing same error.
I have followed same documentation for integration. I have implemented basic payment nothing complex.